# Getting url automatically from html

Tags: html, url

i have to copy many urls from a website. To do this i have to click in many many links and then i have to copy the url (and other info) in an excel's file. This process is so slow. I've to do that for about 500 links. Does anybody have a quick solution to do that? Thanks

Comment: This is called a `web crawler` - you would be better off consulting SuperUser on information on how to do this to Excel.

Comment: Have you looked into site scrapping?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this. You will need jQuery and JavaScript enabled on the page you have.

**You can even run this code from Firebug!**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hrefs = [], srcs = [];

    $('[href]').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('href').length) {
            hrefs.push( $(this).attr('href') );
        }
    });

    $('[src]').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src').length) {
            srcs.push( $(this).attr('src') );
        }
    });

    if(srcs.length || hrefs.length) {
        document.write('<h1>href\'s</h1><hr />' + hrefs.join("<br />") + '<hr /><hr /><h1>src\'s</h1><hr />' + srcs.join("<br />"));
    } else {
        document.write('No links found on this page.');
    }
});
```

Those will output you all the links from the elements which contain `href` or `src` attributes.

Comment: sorry i didn't explain so well. I don't have to get urls from just one web page. I have to get urls from many pages inside of a websites. There's a main page with many links and inside of any link there's some urls that i want to copy

Comment: So run this code on every one of your pages.

Comment: so you don't think there's an automatic way to do that right? ...ok, thanks a lot anyway, i really appreciate

Comment: You can write a server-side URL crawler/scraper, set your URL's, and let him store those URL's inside a file or a database table. That would be an easy for anyone expirenced with PHP elementaries :)